# Integrating Hector Quadrotor Gazebo Simulation with RGB-D SLAM

Tags: slam, navigation, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I'm trying to integrate RGB-D SLAM with the Hector Quadrotor model simulation on Gazebo. The idea is to launch the model of the quadrotor with a kinect and use the visual data recovered by the simulated camera in the running RGB-D SLAM.
What's supposed to be done so this can function right? What topics should be called in each launched file so can RGB-D SLAM  Bcan receive data from the simulated Gazebo Kinect?

Thank you! Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94761/integrating-hector-quadrotor-gazebo-simulation-with-rgb-d-slam/) by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 210 on 2013-10-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rock-ass](https://answers.ros.org/users/6716/rock-ass/) on 2014-01-08**:
I have tried to do the same thing, i got it working (although there is some issues). It required to resolve all dependancy issues and to migrate some old packages into Hydro distro, if you're still interested I could give a few pointers..

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-01-08**:
Hi there! Off course, I'm still interested. Can you please give me some tips, maybe even post some packages to download and use them on Hydro? So you are able to use RGB-D SLAM and Hector Quadrotor both on Hydro? I will need RGBD-SLAM running on Ubuntu ARM.
Thank you

**Comment by [rock-ass](https://answers.ros.org/users/6716/rock-ass/) on 2014-01-09**:
Yes i'm able to use them on hydro. I can provide updated source code of rgbdslam package to be able to compile on ROS hydro, i will provide the info today. But you want it on ARM? simulator on arm should be a real pain to setup and probably will be of poor performance

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-01-09**:
The only thing I want for ARM is the RGB-D SLAM package, since I will be using visual stream data for navigation of a real quad. But first I need to put the simulation correctly working on Hydro so that I can make a port of the used algorithms on a Odroid board.

**Comment by [rock-ass](https://answers.ros.org/users/6716/rock-ass/) on 2014-01-10**:
I posted an answer with link to repo, mark it as answered if it helps :) Let me know if you get any results. i am also working on a quadrotor simulation, only i'm using stereo camera only instead of kinect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have pushed the code with resolved issues for hydro distribution to a git repo, here is the address:

https://bitbucket.org/supelis/rgbdslam_freiburg

Try clone it, then try `rosdep install` to get dependancies (not sure if everything is available for ARM architecture) and then call `rosmake` from root directory of the package to compile. Let me know if there will be any issues.

There are example launch files inside the package, see them how to start it working.

---

Originally posted by [rock-ass](https://answers.ros.org/users/6716/rock-ass/) with karma: 55 on 2014-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-03-05**:
Hi there! I wasn't able to access the project till now. I'm trrying ti rosmake but it keeps getting stuck in [ rosmake ] Last 40 linesbdslam: 25.7 sec ]
#include "g2o/types/slam3d/se3quat.h"
^

**Comment by [rock-ass](https://answers.ros.org/users/6716/rock-ass/) on 2014-03-05**:
could you please copy whole rosmake error trace, there should be more information.
It was some time ago, but as far as I remember g2o is an external dependancy, so maybe it;s missing. I'll take a look at it later this evening

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-03-26**:
Hi @rock-ass. I was able to rosmake your pckg with a minor change (add the OctomapROS.h in the folder /opt/ros/hydro/include/octomap_ros/.) But when I try to do roslaunch rgbdslam kinect+rgbdslam.launch, I don't receive any data from the camera (I already confirmed that open_ni launch works)

**Comment by [rock-ass](https://answers.ros.org/users/6716/rock-ass/) on 2014-04-17**:
Hi. That's weird, i have tried that code and i was able to get view, but it was not accurate. Have you tried to view kinect image stream using image_view package?